# Godot: game gets stuck when trying to access local files

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I have a function that gets an id, finds the relevant local text file, and returns the text from the file.

```
func load_file(book_id):
    var file = placeholder_file % str(book_id)
    var f = File.new()
    f.open(file, File.READ)
    var index = 1
    while not f.eof_reached():
        var line = f.get_line()
        text_from_file += line
        index += 1
    f.close()
    return(text_from_file)
```

This function seems to work fine when I run the game in Godot, but when exporting to HTML or Mac the game gets stuck at the exact moment when the function is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Found the source of the issue. Godot doesn't recognize .txt files and doesn't include them in the exported game unless explicitly instructed to do so.

To include .txt files in your exported game use the filter in the export window called: "filters to export non-resource files/folders"